# Как добавить поясняющий текст к радиокнопкам в формах Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть ли какой-то способ сделать что-то подобное для ChoiceField, отрендеренного с виджетом RadioSelect:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
delivery_methods_choices = [
   ('Способ 1', 'Способ 1'),
   ('Способ 2', 'Способ 2'),
   ('Способ 3', 'Способ 3'),
]

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    delivery_method = forms.ChoiceField(choices=delivery_methods_choices, 
                  widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                  label='Способ доставки')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

На всякий случай скажу, что я использую crispy forms, если это нельзя сделать стандартными средствами, может быть в них что-то такое можно провернуть?

Comment: Можно использовать `ModelMultipleChoiceField` и выбирать из модели варианты способа доставки и добавить в модель дополнительные описания и выводить их в шаблоне